# How to get total assets value in dollars of a wallet via web3?

Tags: web3js, tokens, etherscan, ethereumjs, accounts

I want to check the total assets value in dollars of a wallet.

For example, I just want to check how much asset (Ethers, erc20 tokens) does a wallet hold in form of dollars? e.g: 2000$ worth of assets given the wallet address (xyz)

I want to do it via web3

Any lead?

Answer (score 0):

You could get price estimations from [Chainlink Feeds](https://docs.chain.link/data-feeds) this is how some decentralised protocols get the value of assets. If you want something simpler for js you could just call a DEX like 0x, this is an example with the ETH-DAI pair:

https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/price?sellToken=ETH&buyToken=DAI&sellAmount=1000000000000000000

you could just replace the symbols with the address of the tokens.